# magento 2 required is not working category in custom form

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

we adding required entry in magento 2.4 is not working

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
                        {
                            "*": {
                                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                                    "components": {
                                        "sellerCategory": {
                                            "component": "Webkul_Marketplace/js/product/seller-category-tree",
                                            "template" : "Webkul_Marketplace/seller-category-tree",
                                            "filterOptions": true,
                                            "levelsVisibility": "1",
                                            "options": <?= / @noEscape / $block->getCategoriesTree() ?>,
                                            "value": <?= / @noEscape / json_encode($categories) ?>,
                                            "required" : true
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: it all depends on the compoentn itself `Webkul_Marketplace/js/product/seller-category-tree`. Maybe it does not support a `required` field and this means adding it does nothing. Post in the question the component and the template to see more details

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided code, it looks like you are trying to add a required entry to a seller category field on a product page in the Magento 2.4 admin panel. The code you have provided is using the Magento UI component to add this functionality.

To add the required entry, you should add the validation object to the sellerCategory component with a required-entry rule like so:

```
"sellerCategory": {
        "component": "Webkul_Marketplace/js/product/seller-category-tree",
        "template" : "Webkul_Marketplace/seller-category-tree",
        "filterOptions": true,
        "levelsVisibility": "1",
        "options": <?= / @noEscape / $block->getCategoriesTree() ?>,
        "value": <?= / @noEscape / json_encode($categories) ?>,
        "validation": {
            "required-entry": true
        }
    }
```

This should make the seller category field required and show an error message if the field is left blank.

Comment: not working above logic is tried